# Using fixed text together with <%# when databinding in Asp.NET doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

This works:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="EditGridItemLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl="<%# GetCustomUrl() %>">
link
</asp:HyperLink>
```

link value = `http://localhost/MyCustomUrl.aspx`

This doesn't:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="EditGridItemLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl="subfolder/<%# GetCustomUrl() %>">
link
</asp:HyperLink>
```

link value = `http://localhost/subfolder/<%# GetCustomUrl() %>`

I'm doing this in a Column/TemplateField of an Asp.NET GridView.

Am I doing something wrong or is this simply impossible.

Of course I'm using a workaround now where I set the rest of the NavigateUrl value as well, but I was wondering why this isn't working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this instead: `NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("subfolder/{0}", GetCustomUrl()) %>'`.

Databinding expressions for properties of server controls must be the only thing in the property (no mixing with static text in the way you tried).

Answer (score 1):

You should put the whole expression inside the databinding markup:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="EditGridItemLink" runat="server"
    NavigateUrl="<%# "subfolder/" + GetCustomUrl() %>">
link
</asp:HyperLink>
```